# React - how to create attributes dynamically

Tags: reactjs, wai-aria

I have 2 attributes connected to 2 props: `aria-hidden` and `aria-label`.
When `aria-hidden` is true, it only shows that one. If it's false, it shows only `aria-label`.

I wrote this code but it's not DRY... How can I improve it?

```
 render() {
     let svgMarkup = '';

        if (this.props.hidden) {
            svgMarkup = (
                <svg role="img" aria-hidden="true">
                    ...
                </svg>
            );
        } else {
            svgMarkup = (
                <svg role="img" aria-label={ this.props.label }>
                    ...
                </svg>
            );
        }

        return svgMarkup;
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the props on a plain object, then apply the props to your react component using spread syntax:

```
render() {
    const ariaProps = this.props.hidden ?
        { 'aria-hidden': 'true' }
        :
        { 'aria-label': this.props.label };

    return (
        <svg role="img" {...ariaProps}>
            ...
        </svg>
    );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to do something similar but failed on `...` part. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to help! Yes, that spread operator comes in handy!!

Comment: I my  case spread operator is not working and showing unexpected token error